# coordinates and size in a list of lists

Tags: list, function, indexing

```
def build_board(coords,size):
   xss=[]
   xs1=[]
   xs2=[]
   z = [list(element) for element in coords]
   for i in range(0,2):
       xs1.append((False))
       for j in range(0,2)
           s2.append((False))
       xss.append(xs1)
       if z[i][j] == xss[i][j]
           xss[i][j] = True
   return xss
```

The problem I am having with my code is getting to iterate through the list of lists I created of False values and given a coordinate to check whether or not this coordinate exists in the list of lists and if it is then I change that value to True and if its invalid than I return None.
Some examples include:
    build_board([(0,0)],1) → [[True]]
    build_board([(0,0)],2) → [[True, False], [False, False]]

Comment: Please post human readable code. If possible then include jsFiddle.

Comment: I have edited it so that it is more readable, I think my code is readable too